# Cocoapods shared dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, package-managers

I am refactoring a monolithic codebase and want to split it into frameworks, my current situation is as follows:

- App Project, depends on A, B and C
- Framework A
- Framework B, depends on A
- Framework C, depends on A and B

All the above are in the same workspace, and each has his own pods:

- App uses Firebase, Cryptoswift and RxSwift
- Framework A uses Firebase and RxSwift
- Framework B and C use RxSwift

Everything works fine, but at app launch, I see in the log that there are multiple (two) definitions for each framework, for example:

```
RxSwift is implemented in both 'app' and 'frameworka', which implementation will be used is undefined
```

(Tried both "Do no Embed" and "Embed & Sign")

Any ideas?
I am also fine switching to some other package manager if it helps solve the problem...

Thanks in advance!

My Podfile looks something like this:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!

workspace 'App'

project 'App/App'
project 'FrameworkA/FrameworkA'
project 'FrameworkB/FrameworkB'
project 'FrameworkC/FrameworkC'

target 'Appp' do
  project 'App/App'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'CryptoSwift'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
end

target 'FrameworkA' do
  project 'FrameworkA/FrameworkA'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
end

target 'FrameworkB' do
  project 'FrameworkB/FrameworkB'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
end

target 'FrameworkC' do
  project 'FrameworkC/FrameworkC'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
end
```

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly do you link the frameworks? 
I.e. do you embed all the frameworks to your main app target or not?
And how do you link one framework to another framework? by `Embed` or `Do not Embed`?

Comment: Btw, some of the frameworks are built statically and not dynamically (f.e. Firebase), so in the case of firebase you will end up with Duplicate Symbols Errors. Therefore in the podfile you need also to add a script that will remove static framework linkages.

Comment: Hi @arturdev, tried a bunch of different setups, both Do Not Embed and Embed.
I also tried with some simpler dependencies (made a new set of projects with only 1 shared dependency, Kingfisher, which is a much simpler project than Firebase and RxSwift), but got no luck.

I am pretty sure it was a problem with my setup, but given that Swift Package Manager worked fine I felt like it was not worth investigating further. So I just moved all dependencies there and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I did not find a solution to this.
I just ended up moving to Swift Package Manager, which does throw a compiler error (instead of just a line in the console log) when duplicated dependencies are found.
I then realized I could remove the dependencies and that's it.